# Xamarin: How to get a phone number?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, permissions, xamarin.android

I'm writing a test application, on the xamarin for the android. You need to know the phone number. I tried a lot of options. Last:

```
        [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PhoneNumberService))]
    public string GetMyPhoneNumber()
    {
        TelephonyManager mgr = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService) as TelephonyManager;
        return mgr.Line1Number;
    }
```

AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
<`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 [assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState)]
```

On the emulator works well on the phone does not work. Returns an empty string.

How to get a phone number?

Comment: You are getting the phone number on a modem to the actual phone.  So you have to make sure the drivers are installed correctly.  I would start with the Device Manager to see if he device is installed correctly.  The device is probably connected through a USB port and you have to make sure you are using the correct comm number.

Answer (score 1):

[To solve these problems,this link might help you](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7575/get-phone-number)

Try that:

```
            TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;

            mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);

            var Number = mTelephonyMgr.Line1Number;
```

Comment: please do NOT post link only answers.

Comment: This looks awfully similar to what OP has. Care to explain how this is different?